# WordPress categories and posts priting

Tags: wordpress

What is the syntax for printing the sequence of category name and its follow up posts in my new template in a WordPress site? I have tried a lot via Google but all are not working properly.

Comment: What template file are you trying to create/modify? index.php?, archive.php?

Comment: I am just trying to create new template so called sitemap.php showing all the categories and its post.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but here is a simple one (you will have to improve it with the category and posts links at least):

```
<?php $categories=  get_categories(); 
    if( !empty($categories) ):
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <li>
        <?=$category->cat_name?>
        <?php $posts = get_posts($category->cat_id);
            if( !empty($posts) ):
        ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): ?>
                <li><?= $post->post_title; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```